# How to retrieve data in an order from Firestore in reverse order?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making this Quiz android application where I will be storing the record of each user's individual highscore in Cloud FireStore. So I made this collection named users which only has 2 fields- username and highscore. I want to retrieve the username and highscore of the top ten players globally from there to display in the leaderboard. Please let me know how I can do it! Also will it be possible to get the current user's rank?

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 3):

As shown in the documentation on [ordering and limiting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data), you can get the top 10 players with:

```
usersCollection.orderBy("highscore", Direction.DESCENDING).limit(10);
```